# How can I remove the borders of a lightweight chart that is added to a Wordpress website with js?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, lightweight-charts

currently I'm trying to add a chart from the lightweight charts library to my Wordpress website and having troubles to disable the white borders of the chart (look picture).
[lightweight-chart-example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35Q2g.png)

After trying out every single configuration that I found in the documentation (https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/ChartOptions)
i was still not able to disable the borders or at least change the color.

I added the latest version of the library (3.8) to my website header and added this js script to my footer after defining a new div on the site.

```js
const chartOptions = {
    width: 600,
    height: 300,
    layout: {
        background: { type: 'solid', color: '#40444F' },
        textColor: '#d1d4dc',
    },
    grid: {
        vertLines: {
            visible: false,
        },
        horzLines: {
            color: 'rgba(42, 46, 57, 0.5)',
        },
    },
    rightPriceScale: {
        borderVisible: false,
    },
    timeScale: {
        borderVisible: false,
    },
    crosshair: {
        horzLine: {
            visible: false,
        },
    },
};


const chart = LightweightCharts.createChart(document.getElementById('chart_lightweight'), chartOptions);
const areaSeries = chart.addAreaSeries({
              topColor: '#7CE0D6',
              bottomColor: 'rgba(124, 224, 214, 0)',
              lineColor: '#7CE0D6',
              lineWidth: 3
            });
areaSeries.setData([ ... ]);
```

Basically every white line except the text should disappear or at least be in the same color like the background.
Does someone have an idea and can help me?

Comment: You surely can control the styling of that chart with some CSS. You can use the Inspect Element menu item to see the HTML structure with class names. You'll have to hunt for the border element, then figure out a selector for it, and then maybe write CSS to set its margin to 0 or something. This is intricate work, but absolutely worth mastering for anybody working with WordPress.